# Headless testing using content_shell --dump-render-tree

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

I'm trying this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/damondouglas/5972747) on my Kubuntu dart development box with one of my projects(standard unittest htmlconfiguration), I'm not seeing the Browser Output bit for the tests, rather I'm getting this

```
    Content-Type: text/plain
layer at (0,0) size 800x600
  RenderView at (0,0) size 800x600
layer at (0,0) size 800x15
  RenderBlock {HTML} at (0,0) size 800x15
    RenderBody {BODY} at (15,15) size 770x0 [bgcolor=#F8F8F8]
#EOF
#EOF
#EOF
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Command I'm using is

```
content_shell --args --dump-render-tree test/xml2json.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it, you need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/unittest/test_controller.js"></script>
```

To your test html file, its mentioned [here](http://blog.damondouglas.me/) but not in the Gist